# How I can find the page size, page height and width of MS Word Document in Java?

Tags: java, api, apache-poi, document

I need to check page size, height and width  a word document.

I tried with the java POI API but I couldn't find the solution with this.

If there is any solution then please suggest.

Or is there any better API in java please suggest.

Comment: Sadly I'm not on a laptop where I can play with the API.  I think you should use a debugger and see what properties are available to you when you get the POIXMLProperties via `getProperties`.  It could also be something available from the `CTDocument1` from `XWPFDocument.getDocument()` but I couldn't find any quick javadoc on the thing

Answer (score 5):

Lets assume you have simple documents (in .docx format) without different layouts per section, then the following will give you the page size (see also [this blog entry](http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2010/01/04/points-inches-and-emus-measuring-units-in-office-open-xml) for the various unit conversions):

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;

public class DocxPageLayout {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open("example.docx", PackageAccess.READ);
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(opc);
        opc.close();

        CTSectPr sectPr = doc.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr();
        if (sectPr == null) return;
        CTPageSz pageSize = sectPr.getPgSz();
        if (pageSize == null) return;

        double width_cm = Math.round(pageSize.getW().doubleValue()/20d/72d*2.54d*100d)/100d;
        double height_cm = Math.round(pageSize.getH().doubleValue()/20d/72d*2.54d*100d)/100d;

        System.out.println("width: "+width_cm+" cm; height: "+height_cm+" cm");
    }
}
```